# Preventing some apps from appearing on the start menu on vista

Tags: windows-vista

Vista start menu shows your most frequently used apps, which is great, I love it.

However, there are some apps which I use frequently through shell or such, that I do not want to appear on that menu. Winrar, Media Player Classic, Infranview...

I can right click on it to remove it, but it'll return to the menu shortly, how can I set it so that those apps never appear on the start menu.

Comment: Do you mean on the Start Menu's recent list?

Comment: yes i believe so....

Answer (score 1):

I have used the customized the recent items menu to zero and then pinned the items I want to see on a regular basis to the Start Menu creating my own custom start menu with no annoying recent items menu.

Right Click on the Taskbar/Properties/Start Menu/Customize

[image]

You can go through you list of applications and RightClick/Pin to Start Menu any and all programs you want to appear on your start menu.  You can even drag them into any order you wish.

Comment: That's true, but that would mean not having a recent list. I like the recent list, just with exceptions.